# Space/Time Complexity of DFS/Backtracking Question

Tags: performance, time-complexity, depth-first-search, backtracking, space-complexity

I'm writing a function which calculates the max path from one node to another in an adjacency list graph after going through the graph in DFS/backtracking manner. The path will not have any cycles, but can have the same nodes within a different path. Ex: A->B->C->D and A-C->B->D is valid while A-B->A->C->D is not. To avoid cycles, I can use a visited set to add nodes once discovered and pop later on.

The algorithm must go through every possible path from the starting node to end node as it is possible paths with the same nodes, but different ordering will be valued differently.

I believe the algorithm may be O(n!) considering everything in the graph may be connected, but I'm not too sure. I'm a bit new to graphs, so I'm having a hard time understanding the exact space/time complexity of things.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer to consider the concrete graph (tree), where vertices are numbers but not letters. The problem, you want to solve, supposes applying the **Depth First Search** algorithm as you have shown in your requirement.

Assume, we have the graph (tree):

[image]

Relatively of this graph, the max path from one vertex to another vertex must be calculated.

Here is the solution of your problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int maximumSize=10;
vector<int> visited(maximumSize, 0), distances(maximumSize, 0);
vector<int> graph[maximumSize];
int vertices, edges;
void showContentVector1D(vector<int>& input)
{
    for(int index=0; index<input.size(); ++index)
    {
        cout<<input[index]<<", ";
    }
    return;
}
void createGraph()
{
    cin>>vertices>>edges;
    int vertex0, vertex1;
    for(int edge=1; edge<=edges; ++edge)
    {
        cin>>vertex0>>vertex1;
        graph[vertex0].push_back(vertex1);
        graph[vertex1].push_back(vertex0);
    }
    return;
}
void depthFirstSearch(int currentVertex, int previousVertex)
{
    if(visited[currentVertex]==1)
    {
        return;
    }
    visited[currentVertex]=1;
    distances[currentVertex]=0;
    for(int nextVertex : graph[currentVertex])
    {
        if(nextVertex==previousVertex)
        {
            continue;
        }
        depthFirstSearch(nextVertex, currentVertex);
        distances[currentVertex]=max(distances[currentVertex], distances[nextVertex]+1);
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    createGraph();
    depthFirstSearch(1, 0);
    cout<<"distances <- ";
    showContentVector1D(distances);
    cout<<endl;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
6 5
1 4
2 4
3 4
4 5
5 6
```

The first line in the input is `6 5`, where `6` is the quantity of vertices in a graph and `5` is the quantity of edges in a graph.

`1 4`, `2 4`, `3 4`, `4 5`, `5 6` are edges of an provided undirected graph.

Output:

```
distances <- 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

The number `3` is assigned into the index `1` which corresponds to the vertex `1` of the provided undirected graph (tree). Also in the concrete indices the distances `2` and `1` are assigned. Those indices are `4` and `5` correspondingly. As you can see the maximum distance is `3` from the vertex `1` to the vertex `6`.